# Applying the inverse of the Schur complement without matrix-matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices, schur-complement

If one attempts to solve a (block matrix) saddle point problem such as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & -B^T \\
B & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
p
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
f \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
using a Schur complement structure, then one needs to form the inverse of the Schur complement, $S = BA^{-1}B^T$. We are assuming that $A$ is nonsingular but nothing else. It may be indefinite and nonsymmetric. Additionally, $B$ may be rectangular. Herein lies my issue. Generally, we want to avoid matrix-matrix products. And so, if we have to solve something like $CDx=b$ for invertible matrices $C$ and $D$, we might do a two step process:

1. Solve $Cy=b$.
2. Solve $Dx=y$.

This is done all the time when using a Krylov solver with preconditioning (if I'm off base please correct me), for example.

However, to apply $S^{-1}$ to some vector $b$, we need to solve $Sx=b$ or equivalently $BA^{-1}B^Tx=b$ also without forming matrix-matrix products. There has to be a standard way of doing this, but I have not been able to track it down or come up with one on my own, since $B$ need not be nonsingular or even square. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't think I fully understand your comment. I don't know how I would implement your suggestion. What I really want is $S^{-1}b$. As is usually the case, I will compute the action of the inverse by solving $Sx=b$. Therefore, x is unknown and $B^Tx$ cannot be computed directly (at least not in the straight forward way as a matrix-vector product).

Comment: I misread your question, never mind

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you for the interest in my question anyway. Your comment is helpful on some level at least since a Krylov solver such as GMRES only needs access to the action of $S$ and not its inverse on various vectors. That might be the best that can be done.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 Are you able to supply a reference re GMRES and $S$? I too am trying to invert $S$ in order precondition a system.

Comment: @Olumide This review [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~liesen/Publicat/BenGolLie05.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjGqcSZroeDAxX-IkQIHRt9Cy4QFnoECBwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0vUw1pWoIMgNi5GkiYTlxg) is the best reference I could find. Depending on your application, it likely has what you need. In short, what I said is basically correct. People find a problem-dependent preconditioner for $S$ and then use GMRES since it does not need access to $S$, just it's action.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 Thanks for the reference. Can you point me to the page and paragraph please? I am currently reading the sections of the same paper with some hope of finding a suitable approximate inverse of $S$ -- see (10.12) etc. Nonetheless, I am interested in reasons for preferring GMRES over CG.

Comment: @Olumide This is really a separate question than how to deal with a Schur complement. There is no reason to favor GMRES over CG. I imagine if the system is SPD there is never a reason to use GMRES over CG. If it is not SPD, it's crazy to attempt to use CG. Unless I'm mistaken it's as simple as that and the current topic of a Schur complement has no impact on such considerations. Note that as written a saddle point problem is NOT symmetric so it cannot be SPD. But S could still be SPD.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 Based on my googlings there is such a thing as a symmetric saddle point matrix. (I can see your system is not symmetric but mine is.) Are you able to point me to the page and paragraph of the paper that explains about "GMRES only needs access to the action of $$ and not its inverse".

Comment: @Olumide This is the very nature of GMRES (or CG) being a Krylov solver. If you need more details on GMRES I would recommend making your own separate question. If you do so and point me to it I might have a crack at answering.